# Why are NASA etc so good at hitting tiny targets in tiny time windows?

Tags: projectile, rocket-science, space-travel, nasa

NASA have a tendency to arrive at targets that are so far away, within seconds of ETA, and statements like " it's like throwing an object from New York and having it hit a particular key on a keyboard in San Francisco" ([link](https://what-if.xkcd.com/82/)) are made to describe how amazing that is.

Now, it's clear that it's literally many many orders of magnitude beyond human capability in any way to hit a key in SF from NY. Yet NASA consistently do so, so what exactly is the difference here?

I understand it is much easier to plan in space, which consists of extremely predictable forces to work with (e.g. the gravity and motion of the planets), and very few confounding forces (e.g. air resistence), but does that explain all of it?

Aren't there unpredictable things in space too, like [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail) and [imperfections in planet gravity](https://www.esa.int/Applications/Observing_the_Earth/FutureEO/GOCE/Earth_s_gravity_revealed_in_unprecedented_detail), as well as difficulties like time-delays in communication, manufacturing imperfections, etc?

Comment: They don’t throw it and forget about it, hoping it hits. They track and see what it is doing.

Comment: @JonCuster yes that certainly improves the odds, but I ask again - does that cover all of it? Guiding a drone to press a button somewhere else in the world doesn't seem like such an impressive feat, so I'm not sure what point Randall was making in the linked comic!

Comment: They do sometimes miss. A joint venture between USA and UK to land a probe on Mars crashed, because USA was doing calculations based on Miles and UK was doing calculations in Kilometers. It came in a "bit too hot" and smashed on landing, but it hit the right planet :-).

Comment: @KDP - and various other probes have missed… Mars seems particularly hard for some reason.

Comment: They calculate very accurately and only have a limited amount of fuel for fine tuning vectoring corrections.

Comment: @KDP missing due to mistakes doesn't add to the question as I am more interested in how they are able to do it, even without mistakes. However, mentioning that they are so good at calculations and have very little leeway to make corrections beyond that is very relevant to the question and would need to be covered by an answer, hopefully!

Comment: Would [space.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the launch team hands the S/C off to deep-space-navigation. For Mars orbit insertion of landing, there are 3 telemetry corrections maneuvers (TCM) at the beginning, with 3 correcting 2 correcting 1.

Then on the long trip delta-DOR navigation (timing w/ baseline pulsars) builds very high precision (since the tracked object has a transmitter on it). During approach, there are 3 (or was it 4?) TCMs, maybe starting a week out? And then the last opportunity to change the S/C is fours before entry.

Nav tells EDL: The S/C will go through "this" plane (the B plane... 1km x 1km) within a one second window. At that point, control (which there is none outside the light-cone) is handed to EDL, or approach descent landing, or orbit insertion team--which ever is appropriate.

Regarding defective parts, get a part to space is very hard. To get a hammer into space, you need to know which tree the wood came from, and you need to track all other hammers made from that tree, or even the whole forest. One failure, and the handle is no longer space qualified. Same for the iron: you know the mine, you know iron ore from that mine performed elsewhere.

In attaching the head to the handle, the entire procedure is writing dow and reviewed before the book goes to the clean room. Procedures may be rehearsed. The tech who does the work has two QA engineers watching the attachment processes, and calling out a mistakes.

The finished hammer goes into bonded storage, where someone always has custody or control of it--all documents up the ying yang. Humidity and temperature are recorded for the life of the hammer.

The hammer may be vibe, shock, hot/cold, and vacuum tested. In the space simulator (see JPL's--a nation historic monument), the sun's heat load is simulated.

Similar hammers are vibe, shock, hear/cold, tested to failure to compute the margin.

If you have 1000 hammers, a huge batch is used and they are "burned in"--se Weibull Distribution and Failure analysis---failures are most likely early or late, so the minimum is calculated to be during the mission.

The hammer also goes under EMC and EMI compatibility testing.

Also: you don't fly Apple's newest hammer--you get one that is 10 years old because it has been space qualified (class S).

Did I mention radiation hardness requirements, and SEU sensitivity?

Above all that are planetary protection requirements.

Regarding radiation forces and what not, they are included, but over 40 years can go south. See "Pioneer Anomaly".

For gravity...we have a lot of information about planets we've orbited many times (see: "Radio Science")--the harder part is dealing with non-newtonian gravity and the warp coordinates of our solar system. See "Parameterized Post Newtonian" and "JPL Barycentric Coordinates".

Comment: These days we're using a lot of off the shelf parts. NICER collects its data using $8 automotive microcontrollers (and actually *can* navigate using pulsars: I don't know what you referred to above). I was surprised that for TESS, there were originally no radiation tolerance requirements at all: I had to advocate for radiation testing of key parts. Both NICER and TESS are working well, deep into extended missions. Go figure.

Comment: @JohnDoty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-DOR  ..$8? is that class S? https://nepp.nasa.gov/nepag/info/differences/differences_in_parts_classes.htm

Comment: What does Delta-DOR have to do with pulsars?

Comment: Class S? Why would I choose class S junk when I can choose a rugged, reliable automotive-grade part?

Comment: @JohnDoty *quasars

Comment: Quasars and pulsars are different things. Quasars are useless for timing: their use is to establish a non-rotating reference frame.